# Count number of matching paired values in array in R

Tags: r

Rookie question. I'm looking for a simple way in R to count the number of matching pair of values in an array such as

```
c("A","A","A") # 3 matched pairs
c("A","B","A") # 1 matched pair
c("A","B") # 0 matched pair
```

etc

Thank you

Comment: The conditon of matching pair is not clear

Comment: can you use `table(c("A","A","A"))`?

Comment: Within an array, I want to find out number of possible pairs of same values.

I guess the the way to do it is, for each unique value (z), I want to find choose(count(z),2), and then sum up those for all other unique values in the array. Hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to find all possible pairs of identical elements, where their order does not matter. Then:

```
matchPairs <- function(x) sum(choose(table(x), 2))

matchPairs(c("A", "A", "A"))
# [1] 3
matchPairs(c("A", "B", "A"))
# [1] 1
matchPairs(c("A", "B"))
# [1] 0
matchPairs(c("A", "A", "A", "B"))
# [1] 3
matchPairs(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"))
# [1] 4
matchPairs(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A"))
# [1] 7
```

Comment: Sorry, order does not matter. For example:

For the last set, it would be (4 choose 2) + (2 choose 2).

Comment: My bad, that's indeed what I meant and (4 choose 2) + (2 choose 2) is indeed 7.

Comment: @DonZhang, perhaps then the answer can be accepted.